# django filter returns infinite loop

Tags: django

When I filter the storehouses of a company, it returns the error:
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

```
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    company = Company.objects.get(owner=self.request.user)
    stores = Store.objects.filter(company=company.id)
    if len(stores) <= 1:
        return Response(data={'detail': 'At least one storehouse is required'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return self.delete(request, *args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: What's in the `delete` method?

Comment: is destroy method, im using DRF with ModelViewSet

Comment: So in your destroy you call the destroy => loop

Comment: changed it to self.destroy(request, *args,**kwargs) but same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `DestroyAPIView` then calling `self.delete()` will return it to [destroy method](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L216). Instead of `self.delete()` you should call the super method.

```
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    company = Company.objects.get(owner=self.request.user)
    stores = Store.objects.filter(company=company.id)
    if len(stores) <= 1:
        return Response(data={'detail': 'At least one storehouse is required'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return super().destroy(request, *args,**kwargs)
```